# php extends a class without rename it

Tags: php, class, constructor, rename, extends

few weeks ago i found on the web a script to use the __constructor and __get for extends the class w/o rename it

that script was able put in the main class all other class wich extends itself 
so was possible make something like

```
class mainclass { 
   function __constructor(){  ...something...  }
   function __get(){  ...something else...  }
}
class subclass extends mainclass { 
   function test(){ return "works? how?";  }
}
$class = new mainclass;
$class->test();
```

that script was very interesting but i've lost it, some one know where find it or how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean someting like this: [Partial Classes](http://www.toosweettobesour.com/2008/05/01/partial-classes-in-php/)

Comment: yes was something like that but wasn't required add always in the class the metods __get __set and __call